# SQL Select SUM() Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query, I add that SUM() in "sum(count(distinct idDriver)) as Conductores", but i get this error:

Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function

```
    select
    department as Delegación,
    company as Compañía,
    config as Configuración,
    docs as Documentos,
    sum(count(distinct idDriver)) as Conductores,
    sum(ko) as "Doc. incorrectos",
    round(sum(ko)/(docs*count(distinct idDriver))*100) as "% incumplimiento"
 from
    (
    select 
       cd.name as department,
       cfg_g.name as config, 
       c.businessname as company, 
       (select count(*) from widoc_config where idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and idstatus=71001 and required=true) as docs, 
       wd.idDriver, 
       cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup, 
       cfg.idwidocconfig, 
       cfg.iddocument, 
       a.idstatus, 
       if(a.idstatus=43002,"0","1") as ko
    from
        widoc_config_group cfg_g
        join widoc_config cfg on cfg.idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and cfg.idstatus=71001 and cfg.required=true
        join widoc_client wc on wc.idclient=cfg_g.idclient and wc.idstatus=71001
        join client c on c.idclient=wc.idclientassociated and c.idstatus_client=5004
        join widoc_driver wd on wd.idwidocclient=wc.idwidocclient and wd.idstatus=71001
        join driver d on d.iddriver=wd.iddriver and d.idstatus=71001
        join widoc_fulfill_driver fd on fd.idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and fd.idwidocdriver=wd.idwidocdriver
        left join attachment_group a on a.idclient=wc.idclientAssociated and a.iddocument=cfg.iddocument and a.idstatus!=43004 and a.idFK=wd.idDriver
        left join client_department cd on cd.idClientDepartment=wc.idClientDepartment and cd.idStatus=71001
    where
         cfg_g.idclient = 3683
        #wc.idclientAssociated = 1865
        and cfg_g.identitytype=73003
        and cfg_g.idstatus=71001
        ) t
 group by department,company;
```

Where do I have to put this HAVING code, and what should I have to write? Thanks!

Comment: Having should come after group by also you should use all the non aggregated columns in group by list

Comment: But what should I have to write? If i write this after group by: HAVING sum(count(distinct idDriver)) it gives me the same error.

Comment: What is sum(count()) supposed to do? I don't think that makes any sense

Comment: In ANSI SQL, and in MySQL with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode turned on, you _can't_ select columns which don't also appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.  Given the large size of your query, I can't suggest an exact fix.

Comment: Because drivers can be in different departments but I want all their iD's.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
sum(count(distinct idDriver)) as Conductores,
sum(ko) as "Doc. incorrectos",
round(sum(ko)/(docs*count(distinct idDriver))*100) as "% incumplimiento"
```

You cannot nest aggregate functions: if you think about it, `sum(count(...))` makes no sense. I suspect that you want:

```
count(distinct idDriver) as Conductores,
sum(ko) as "Doc. incorrectos",
round(sum(ko)/(docs*count(distinct idDriver))*100) as "% incumplimiento"
```

Also, you should enumerate all non-aggregate columns in the `group by` clause. Even if currently missing columns are functionnaly dependant on the ones being listed, this is still a best practice in SQL (and a rule on most RDBMS, including MySQL unless option `FULL_GROUP_BY_ONLY` is disabled). So you want to change this:

```
group by department,company
```

To:

```
group by department, company, config, docs
```